# Get selected menu item's index value in the navigation drawer

Tags: android

I have implemented navigation drawer, it is working fine. The only problem that I have to make selected item to deselect when the navigationdrawer closes. I wonder how could I able to get the index value of selected menu item.

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
      menuItem.setChecked(false);
   }
)}
```

Comment: could you please provide a code sample?

Comment: Check my answer hope that is helpful for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way to do is store menu item ID in variable e.g **checkedItemID**

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
      menuItemID=menuItem.getItemId();
   }
)}
```

> Then on implement

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            // Do whatever you want here

         navigationView.getMenu().findItem(menuItemID).setChecked(false);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // Do whatever you want here
        }
    };
// Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Answer (score 5):

Make a variable **position** of `int` **datatype**. Firstly set its value to 0 and onNavigationItemSelected change its value to `menuItem` index(like 0 or 1 or 2 and so on).Now this **position** will provide you the **index** of selected `menuItem`.

```
int position = 0;
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.first:
                position = 0;
                break;
           case R.id.second:
                position = 1;
                break;
           case R.id.third:
                position = 2;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: what happens if you change the order of the menu items? you have to remember to update the case statement

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get navigation item at position 0 getItem(index) will give you desired item

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(selectedposition).setChecked(false);
```

also use this link for reference for getting seleted item http://thegeekyland.blogspot.in/2015/11/navigation-drawer-how-set-selected-item.html

use below code for getting selected position

```
int selectedposition= 0;

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.firstitemid:
                    selectedposition= 0;
                    break;
               case R.id.seconditemid:
                    selectedposition= 1;
                    break;
               case R.id.thirditemid:
                    selectedposition= 2;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: But I need to know clicked menu item index.

Comment: Again, I need to know selected item index number `navigationView.getMenu().getItem(selectedMenuItemIndex).setChecked(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way that worked for me

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int index = (item.getItemId() % item.getGroupId())-1;
    ....
}
```

I think, this would be much more efficient than using For loop or Switch case.

If you still have problems then my suggestion would be to check your Item Id and group Id in Log-cat so that you would have a better understanding of what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need, it deselects and selects the new one

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(item.getItemId());
```

And it should go at the bottom of onNavigationItemSelected.

To make it more clear here's an example

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            controller.setFragment(new HomeFragment());
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            controller.setFragment(new SettingsFragment());
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(autoLogin, false);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(item.getItemId());
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First assign your navigationMenu to a class field

```
private NavigationView navigationView;
private int currentPosition;
...
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Now in the menu callback you can loop over the menu items :

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    for (int i=0;i<navigationView.getMenu().size();i++){
        if(item==navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i)){
            currentPosition=i;
            break;
        }
    }
 ....
}
```

You can change the order of the menu items without breaking anything